# C# Web User Control (DLL) isn't rendering any GUI on Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, webusercontrol

I made a user control (.ascx), implemented its functionality and after testing made a DLL by publishing the website.
I then made a new website project in Visual Studio and add a reference of User Control DLL in it, registered it on the page where I need to use it and then refer it there.
My code isn't giving any errors but it is not rendering any GUI on run.

I am using this for registeration of user controll dll on aspx page where I need to use it.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="App_Web_submodule.ascx.cdca7d2" Namespace="ASME" tagPrefix= "UC" %>
```

During my search I found these two sites " https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx " & " http://www.nathanblevins.com/blog/2008/06/09/compile-a-web-user-control-into-a-dll-net-c/ " and they are following exactly same steps as I do but may be there is something that I am missing?

Comment: Please see the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. What have you tried and do you have code?

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** shukriya!

Comment: I didn't add anything specific, it is a simple user control (.ascx) which has some labels, TextBoxes and Buttons, I made its dll and refer it in some other Web App.

Comment: <%@ Register Assembly="App_Web_submodule.ascx.cdca7d2" Namespace="ASME"  tagPrefix= "UC" %>

I am using this for registeration of user controll dll on aspx page where I need to use it.

Comment: so your assembly containing your web user control is named `App_Web_submodule.ascx.cdca7d2.dll`? That is a pretty weird name, if  I may say so.

Comment: its done now, I was missing class Name in User Conrtrol and thats why it wasn't compiling it to be used as dll